# Timeout OrientDB Error in NodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb3.0

I have developed NodeJS application and using OrientDB database in our project. Everything works fine until we left the application idle for sometime. We are facing time out error in OrientDB.

Please find the error below:

```
Unhandled rejection OrientDB.ConnectionError [2]: read ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection.handleSocketError (/home/myuser/sample_app/node_modules/orientjs/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:352:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Please advice